# Does Polymer Dart have something similar to Angular's ng-switch?

Tags: dart, switch-statement, polymer

Is there something in Polymer to do a `switch` statement in markup?
I have this component I want to build, and it could have a ton of "IFs" to simply display some code. I was wondering if Polymer has something like Angular's `ng-switch`?

Example:

```dart
<div ng-switch="selection">
  <div ng-switch-when="settings">Settings Div</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="home">Home Span</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>default</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Polymer you only have `

```
<template if="{{selection == 'settings'}}">....</template>
<template if="{{selection == 'home'}}">....</template>
<template if="{{!(selection == 'settings' && selection == 'home')}}">....</template>
```

which is obviously not as terse as `ng-switch`.

In Polymer 0.8 `<template if...>` and `<template repeat...>` are built as a custom element. The same can be done for switch.

Comment: Thank you Gunter, but I'm looking for a switch, something less verbose than a bunch of "if".
Also, do they have "else" on markup?

Comment: Currently there is only `repeate` and `if`. See also my updated answer.

Comment: oh, cool, so I guess I can build my own :D
I was just hoping, hoping very hard...that this was done just like angular.

Comment: Currently not, but the approach they take with 0.8 probably leads to more such structural elements.